# Proving $D(\Omega)$ is not dense in $H^1(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, trace

I'm trying to show that $D(\Omega)$, i.e. the classical space of test functions, is not dense in $H^1(\Omega)$. To show this, I consider the closure of $D(\Omega)$ in the $H^1$ norm, call it $D$.

Let $u \in D$. By definition of closure, there exists a sequence $\{u_k\}_k  \in D(\Omega)$ such that $||u_k -u||_{H^1} \rightarrow 0$. If now I consider the classical trace operator $\gamma : H^1(\Omega) \rightarrow L^2(\partial \Omega)$, by its continuity I have: $$\gamma(u_k) \rightarrow \gamma(u)$$

But since $\gamma(u_k)=0$, it follows $\gamma(u)=0$. Therefore, in $D$ every function has $0$ trace, and then a generic function in $H^1$ with *non-zero* trace cannot be reached as a limit in $H^1$ of elements of $D$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes this is correct for a Lipschitz domain $\Omega$ where the trace theorem holds and in fact one can characterise the Sobolev space $H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$ as functions having zero trace on the boundary. It largely depends on how your Sobolev spaces have been defined and on which sets you are looking at. A more general approach would be to show you cannot approximate the constant function arbitrary well by smooth functions with compact support in the Sobolev norm.

Comment: @Cryptokyo Thanks for checking. So, how can I prove this in general?

Comment: @Cryptokyo My Professor just said: "Prove that, in general, $D(\Omega)$ is not dense in $H^1(\Omega)$. He gave no info about $\Omega$. What other argument would you use?

Comment: This statement fails for a lot of domains. For example it is not true for $\Omega = \mathbb R^n$. However, you can prove it for arbitrary bounded domain using Friedrichs inequality (prove that the constant functions doesn't satisfy it).